# Firebase token always expired

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On all tablets of one model with custom ROM i geting firebase token, send it to server, but it always expired. What's can be wrong? Get it when open app this way:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

And onTokenRefreshed:

```
 @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
   String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    Globals.getInstance().Token = refreshedToken;
    SaveToken();
}
```

On other devices everything ok.

Comment: are you getting refresh token as null

Comment: No, it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app renew the fcm token when you run the method. Use below method. It never cause fcm token to be expire, even you clear the app data. Only uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token.

1. First Create a java class for FirebaseInstanceIdService. It is only 
   called when a new token is generated.

**FcmInstanceIdService.java**

```
public class FcmInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{    
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(){
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.FCM_Token),recent_token);
        editor.commit();    
    }
}
```

2. Add FcmInstanceIdService in AndroidManifest.xml file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".FcmInstanceIdService">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

3. Add Strings name FCM_PREF & FCM_Token to strings.xml file.

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="FCM_PREF">com.example.YourAccountName.AppName.fcm_pref</string>
<string name="FCM_Token">com.example.YourAccountName.AppName.fcm_token</string>
```

4. When you want to get the fcm token, use below code in your activity.

**YourActivityName.java**

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_Token), "");
```